# Stopping Children from being stretched when parent Layout container is scaled through animation in Android

Tags: android

How to Stop Children controls from being stretched when parent Layout container is scaled through Android's **ScaleAnimation** ??

Following Images will explain what i want to do.

**Note: I have tried setting the children's Width in pixels but in vain**

**Layout Before Stretching** OR View a large image **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMQU9.jpg)**

[image: Layout Before Stretching]

**Layout After Stretching** OR View a large image **[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRvec.jpg)**

[image: Layout After Stretching]

Your helpis greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [yydl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312499/yydl) for pointing [Android Left Panel Library](http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/browse/#git/LeftNavBarLibrary) to be used for such purpose.

It provides everything built in i was trying to do myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put children with width fill_parent in layout container with fixed width, or wrap_content.

PS: if you would use actual IntelliJ IDEA, you will have layout previwer which is nice tool to debug it ( there is free community edition )